# Pass variable into url with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

on my website I use Cake PHP and I have an url like this for an article:

/article/testx?name=Stefy

I would like to do a kind of "mod rewrite" and have an url like this:

/name/Stefy

I tried to do it from routes.php but I don't know how to do.
I checked on CakePHP website about "pass" function in array and other topics here on StackOverflow but I can't find a solution, probably because I am a beginner with CakePHP.
Can you help me please?

I thought I should something like this:
Router::connect('/name/:id', array('controller' => 'articoli', 'action' => 'display','testx?name=$id') );

but of course it doesn't work. I think I have to use "pass" in the routes.php

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

yeah, you kinda do have to use "pass":

```
Router::connect('/name/:id', 
    array('controller' => 'articoli', 'action' => 'display'), 
    array('pass' => array('id')));
```

you can than generate links like this:

```
$this->Html->link('Title', array('action' => 'display', 'id' => 1));
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much.
How can I do "echo" of the variable?
For example the url will be something like /name/Stefy
How can I show just "Stefy" in the page?
Thank you!

Comment: i dont know what you mean! "stefy" is not the id but a slug?

Comment: I try to explain it better...
My url /article/testx?name=Stefy usually shows a page with inside a code like this:

The name you selected is: <b><?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?></b>

and so it is shown: The name you selected is:  <b>Stefy</b>


I would like to have a kind of "Mod Rewrite" and when I go to an url like: /name/Stefy
it will show: The name you selected is: <b>Stefy</b>

if I go to an url like: /name/Mark
will show:  The name you selected is:  <b>Mark</b>


I am not sure it's a slug, maybe yes.
Thank you!

Comment: yeah, you should use SluggedBehavior etc to create slugs for your names and then use those in your route. that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

Router::connect('/:slug',array('controller' => 'salons', 'action' => 'details'), array('pass' => array('slug')));